# How to open link in new tab and close it immediately after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have two links on a page. When I click on the first link, I want the link to open in a new tab and close immediately when the page is loaded. I want the same to happen for second link.

Also, how can I automate this step for 'n' number of times?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this function:

```
function openUrl(url, title) {
    if (!title) {
        title = 'Just another window';
    }
    var x = window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');

    x.blur();
    x.close();
}
```

This function accepts two arguments: URL (the new window's URL) and title (the title that will be displayed on the new created window).

Comment: What is the purpose of the blur() method being called?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://google.ca" id='idForm'>
      <div>
        <button type='submit' >post</button>
      </div>
     </form>
  </body>  
<script>

    $("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });

</script>
</html>
```